# Laravel Artisan command output printed from a dependency

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I'm writing a custom artisan command who has a service as dependency:

```php
class InstallCommand extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'mycommand:install';

    /** @var InstallService */
    private $installService;

    public function __construct(InstallService $installService)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->installService = $installService;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $this->installService->install();
    }
}
```

The `InstallService::install` method prints some logs and I would like in this case the output to be handled as the command output.

The solution I found is as follows:

```php
class InstallService
{
    /** @var Command */
    private $cmd;

    public function setCommand(Command $cmd)
    {
        $this->cmd = $cmd;
    }

    public function install() {

       $logText = "Some log";
       if($this->cmd != null){
          $this->cmd->info($logText);
       } else {
          Log::debug($logText);
       }
    }
}
```

And in the command constructor:

```php
class InstallCommand extends Command
{
  public function __construct(InstallService $installService)
  {
      parent::__construct();
      $installService->setCommand($this);
      $this->installService = $installService;
  }
```

Is there a way to detect if the triggerer is an artisan command independently within the service and then avoid the need to have the `InstallService::setCommand` method?

Once detected I want the output to be styled in the same way as that printed by the command with `$this->info()`. Is it possible, for example, to retrieve the command instance and call the same method?

Comment: so you want to know if it is running in the console right ?

Comment: I think you can use simple `echo` from your service. But this can be a problem when you trigger the command from frontend and use `dispatch` handler.

Comment: Sorry i edited the question: I want to know if it is running in the console and, if yes, to print output styled in the same way as calling `Command::info()`. I tried with `echo` but the output style differs from that of the command

Answer (score 0):

You can do a check with https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.html
runningInConsole() method

App::runningInConsole()

```
if(App::runningInConsole())
{
//implicitly set command
}
```

**Update:**

info prints using write(str message,bool newline)
so inside the command use write method.

```
$this->output->write('this is the output', false);
```

Comment: Sorry i edited the question: I know how to detect if it is running in the console but i also want to print output styled in the same way as calling Command::info().

Comment: i updated the response according to your comment, hope you get the desired behavior.

Comment: I want to output some text from the service called by the command and not from the command itself